# How should I tag betrayal at the house on the hill?

Tags: discussion, tags

`Betrayal at the house on the hill` has a ludicrously long title. Too long to be a complete tag on this site (>25 characters). Currently I'm tagging my question as BatHotH...which is less than perfect. Is there a better option? Have I created a monster with that tag?

Is there a better way to tag it?

- Betrayal-at-the-house
- Betrayal-house-hill
- Betrayal-athoth

?

Answer (score 4):

Well, for a start, it's actually called [Betrayal at House on the Hill](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/10547/betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill), although that's still 24 chars, plus 5 for the spaces.

My vote would be for [betrayal-at-house-on-hill](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betrayal-at-house-on-hill) (25 chars). Having `betrayal` at the start is valuable, as the tag will auto-complete for new questions, and also in searches.

Comment: They all seem to be tagged "betrayal-on-house-at-hill" now... oops?

Comment: @Jefromi - Looks like the OP made that change (I'd been waiting for a little more consensus before applying). Fixed now. ;)